# Scala Play JDBC can't connect to MySQL when running in a docker container

Tags: mysql, scala, docker, jdbc, playframework

I am trying to make a scala play web application (RESTful). I have been following the play tutorial for SQL connections but I am having trouble connecting my container with the play application to the container with the mysql container. After a lot of debugging I have realised that the scala application does work when ran locally instead of in the docker container.

code from application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:49160/testdb"
db.default.username="root"
db.default.password="password"
db.default.host="localhost"

# db connections = ((pyhsical_core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
fixedConnectionPool = 17

database.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  spades:
    build: ./spades
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./spades/cardsatra-spades:/home/app
    ports:
      - 49162:9000

  database:
    build: ./database
    ports:
      - 49160:3306
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
```

sbt application dockerfile

```
ARG OPENJDK_TAG=8u232
FROM openjdk:8u232

ARG SBT_VERSION=1.3.7

# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-1.3.7.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-1.3.7.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-1.3.7.deb && \
  rm sbt-1.3.7.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

EXPOSE 9000

RUN mkdir /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY cardsatra-spades/entrypoint.sh .

CMD ["/bin/sh", "/home/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh just runs sbt clean and sbt run

database dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8

# ENV MYSQL_DATABASE stormlight
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password
ENV MYSQL_USER mysql
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD password 
ENV DATABASE_HOST db
```

scala endpoint (ommitted the class and imports) -> this is on the GET /news/all route

```
def doSomething: Future[Vector[Newspost]] = Future {
    db.withConnection { conn =>
      var res: Vector[Newspost] = Vector[Newspost]()

      val statement = conn.createStatement
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM news")


      while(resultSet.next) {
        val id = resultSet.getInt("id")
        val title = resultSet.getString("title")
        val body = resultSet.getString("body")
        val date = resultSet.getString("date")

        res = res :+ Newspost(id, title, body, date)
      }
      res
    }
  }(dec)
```

When I run the database with docker-compose up database and the play application locally using sbt run the endpoint works correctly and returns the Newspost vector

When I run both applications via docker-compose up I get a huge stack trace

```
spades_1    | Getting req!
spades_1    | [error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler - 
spades_1    | 
spades_1    | ! @7emkpm006 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/news/all] ->
spades_1    |  
spades_1    | play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.]]
spades_1    |   at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:332)
spades_1    |   at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
spades_1    |   at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:421)
spades_1    |   at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:417)
spades_1    |   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:453)
spades_1    |   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
spades_1    |   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
spades_1    |   at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
spades_1    |   at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
spades_1    |   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
spades_1    | Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

I have omitted most of the scala code as its working not in docker I assume there is no issue with the scala code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should point your application to the other container, not `localhost` which implies the same "machine" from the system's perspective (i.e. same container):

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://database:49160/testdb"
```

You can make this setting environment-dependent of course, so that the app works in development mode and in `docker-compose` mode.

Comment: This is correct. The hostname should not be localhost but the docker container name.

Comment: This worked, but only when I also changed the database port to 3306 in the docker-compose.yml and in the db.default.url . I am not sure why it doesn't work on port 49160 but at least its working now, thanks

Comment: @mattematt It does not work on port `49160` because you re-mapped it to `3306` in your docker compose file, it means that internal  `49160` port visible from outside as `3306` port.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko The short [port syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-1) is `HOST:CONTAINER`, so it looks fine to me. @mattematt I'd try two things: 1) Defining port mappings as strings 2) Using a non-emphemeral port (e.g. `4444`). Either way, `docker ps` and netcat are probably the best tools for checking this. One will tell you what is exposed in by the container, the other if you can actually connect to something.